# Simple C++ Array search

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am taking a C++ class this semester in school and was given a project where I have to write a program that asks the user for a number and stops when they enter 0 and then store the numbers into an array and then prompt the user to enter a number and search the array for that number, if it is a number stored in the array then I return "FOUND!" and if not I return "NOT FOUND!"
I have to do the search through a function.

I have everything done for the program except for the search function. I was told to research on the internet how to do this and apply it to my program, but the problem is in this class we were only taught how to use the while() loop and every search function I find seems to just go over my head since this is a very basic c++ class.

Could anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Boolean function `search` which takes three parameters: an `array`, the `size` of this array, and a `target` number to search for (I use a `for` loop):

```
bool search(int array[], int size, int target)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (array[i] == target)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

You can then print `"FOUND!"` or `"NOT FOUND!"` whenever `search` return `true` or `false`, respectively.

Comment: Ok. So When I would call this function what would the parameters be?
'num' is the name of my array and the maximum size of my array is '25'.
I was thinking I could do search(num, 25) but then I don't know what to put for the target parameter when calling it.

Sorry if I sound dumb, I'm not too good or experienced with this language =/

Comment: In the OP, you write: *"... prompt the user to enter a **number** and search the array for that **number**..."*. This is the `target` you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The function can look the following way

```
bool search( int a[], int size, int value )
{
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < size && a[i] != value ) i++;

    return ( i != size );
}
```

Using of the function will be the following

```
if ( search( YourArray, ActualNumberOfArrayElements, value ) )
{
    std::cout << "Value " << value << " found in the array" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Value " << value << " did not find in the array" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's really C++, you should use C++ features to do that. First, let's look at full source code for that program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Array of numbers with dynamic size
    // At first it contains 0 elements
    vector<int> haystack;

    // "Forever" loop
    for (;;) {
        // The new number
        int n;

        // Input that number.
        // Do you know that `cin >> c` returns `cin`
        // to let us write something like
        // `cin >> a >> b`? It works like
        // `(cin >> a) >> b` =>
        // `cin >> b` =>
        // `cin` which doesn't go anywhere. It's just `cin`.
        // Also, `cin` can be implicitly cast (um, I mean "transformed")
        // to `bool`. So the following line not
        // just asks for a number, but tests if
        // number input succeeded.
        if (!(cin >> n)) {
            // User pressed Ctrl+Z to end input
            // or it was something like "abc"
            // instead of a number.
            break;
        }
        if (n == 0) {
            // User gave us zero.
            break;
        }

        // Add new element in an array,
        // save `n` in it
        haystack.push_back(n);
    }

    // Number we will search in that array
    int needle;
    cin >> needle;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Easy way:
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Here's a boolean flag.
    // `true` value in it means that we've currently found
    //        the number
    // `false` means that we still didn't found it
    bool found = false;

    // Iterate over all numbers we've recently got
    // `haystack.size()` is a quantity of that numbers
    // Call to `size()` takes more time than reading value
    // from a variable, so we'd better save it in a variable `ilen`.
    // `size()` returns value of `size_t` type. It's usually an
    // integer without a sign.
    for (size_t i = 0, ilen = haystack.size(); i < ilen; ++i) {
        // Test if i-th number is the one we search for
        if (haystack[i] == needle) {
            // Yay, it is! Set the flag to true.
            found = true;
            // Exit loop, as we don't care for all the other values
            break;
        }
    }

    // Don't ever write `found == true` to test if boolean flag is true.
    // ==, != and other comparison operators do return boolean values.
    if (found) {
        cout << "FOUND" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "NOT FOUND" << endl;
    }
    // Also you could write it with ternary operator ("short if")
    // cout << (found ? "FOUND" : "NOT FOUND") << endl;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Harder ways
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // You could iterate over items in that array like
    // for (vector<int>::const_iterator it = haystack.begin(),
    //      iend = haystack.end(); it != iend; ++it) {
    //     if (*it == needle) { ... }
    //}
    // It's kinda hardcore, but performs well.

    // You could even go nuts and use some stuff from
    // <algorithm> header
    // if (find(haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), needle) !=haystack.end()) {
    //     cout << "FOUND" << endl;
    // } else {
    //     cout << "NOT FOUND" << endl;
    // }
    // Look, ma, no loops!
}
```

Comment: In case you need to use a standalone function to search for that value, you can use the last `<algorithm>` trick from this answer, so you don't even have to write that function!